# Android getStringExtra problems

Tags: android, string, logging, if-statement, android-activity

I am passing a string from one activity to the other. I pass the text "maglist". When i log the string in the next activty it says "maglist" as it should do. BUT, if i do an if statement which asks if the string = "maglist" then is just goes to the else when it should be true. Il show you:

First Activity:

```
        Intent intentRefresh = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.fieldandrurallife.media.InternetRefresh.class);
        String list = "maglist";
        intentRefresh.putExtra("from", list);
        intentRefresh.putExtra("cat", cat);
        startActivity(intentRefresh);
```

Second Activity:

```
    Intent iB = getIntent();        
    String from = iB.getStringExtra("from");
    if(from == "maglist"){
        Log.d("refresh", "From = " + from);
    } else {
        Log.d("refresh", "dident work" + from);
    }
```

I get the LOG of "dident work maglist" when it should be "maglist"
Confused. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: use string methods for comparison. I mean use from.equalsIgnoreCase("maglist"); try this and let me know whether it works or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare strings, use equals instead, for example:

```
if(from.equals("maglist")){
    ...
}
```

[More about compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/265597)

Answer (score 1):

In order to compare two strings you should do `string1.equals(string2);`
 `string1==string2` actually compares the references.

Answer (score 0):

To compare strings you should use 'equals':

```
if(from.equals("maglist")) {
// TO DO
}
else {
//To DO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the isequal method instead of "=="

```
from .equalsIgnoreCase("maglist")
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare Strings using `equals`, use
`if (from.equals("maglist"))`

Answer (score 0):

Intead of == try from.equals("maglist")

Answer (score 0):

change your condition with below one.

```
if(from.equals("maglist")){
        Log.d("refresh", "From = " + from);
    } else {
        Log.d("refresh", "dident work" + from);
    }
```

P.S:- You can not compare String values with equal(==) symbols, As they will return false always other then if both string objects are same.

Answer (score 0):

Right Way to compare The String in java

```
if(from.equals("maglist"))
   {
       ...
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if(from.equals("maglist"))`. If that fails,

try `if(from.contains("maglist"))`